# difference between maximal atlas and atlas in differential manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

i am reading the definition of atlas in differential manifold from U.C De book..

we know differential structure on a manifold is maximal atlas.

but i want to know a counter example to distinguish between maximal atlas and just atlas.

Comment: I think this is a good question; it's symptomatic of your careful approach to learning.

Comment: @kimchilover thanks, please help me to find out its answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identical map $I$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ forms an atlas by itself. However, $\{I, 2 \cdot I \}$ is also an atlas on that manifold. The maximal atlas based on this atlas would be the set of all diffeomorphisms from open subsets to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: but sir which one is maximal?

Comment: i am thinking for new cordinate chat with different open subset and a homeomorphic map

Comment: You probably meant "diffeomorphisms" rather than "homeomorphisms".